# what can i do with that scrollviewer?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollview

- i used a GroupBox with a scrollviewer inside it ..and inside scrollviewer i put a grid and begin to put my controls (3 textblocks and 7 textboxes)
- i can't make scrollviewer to scroll my content ..and i don't know if i miss something to activate it
- here is my xaml code:

  ```
    <GroupBox BorderBrush="#FF0000DD" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Header="General Information" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="363,20,38,486" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                      <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="Auto" ScrollChanged="scrollViewer1_ScrollChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                          <Grid Name="grid1" Height="132">
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Generic ID" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBlock FontSize="14" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Generic Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBlock FontSize="14" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Other Names" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="3" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="4" Padding="0" />
                              <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="5" Padding="0" />
                          </Grid>
                      </ScrollViewer>
                  </GroupBox>
  ```

Comment: The xaml itself seems to work for me (in Kaxaml editor). What is missing is the `scrollViewer1_ScrollChanged` method. Can you share it? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Positioning controls with margins is so wrong... Get rid of this margins thing. Use grid rows/columns properly and all your problems will vanish.

Comment: @ Nicolas Repiquet  i removed margins and still grid appear behind things as in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your GroupBox's Height. It is stretching to fill the entire Window and your content is stretching to Fit. If you limit the size of the GroupBox you will get your VerticalScroll and it will work. I modified your code to this and it works:

```
<GroupBox BorderBrush="#FF0000DD" FontSize="13"  FontWeight="Bold" Header="General Information" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="132" Name="groupBox1"  Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="Auto" ScrollChanged="scrollViewer1_ScrollChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <Grid Name="grid1" Height="132">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Generic ID" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Padding="0" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Generic Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Other Names" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Padding="0" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="2" Padding="0" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="3" Padding="0" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="4" Padding="0" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="textBox6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="197" Grid.Row="5" Padding="0" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</GroupBox>
```

With the result of this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GroupBox BorderBrush="#FF0000DD" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Header="General Information" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1,0,0,129" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
       <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1" Width="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <Grid  Name="grid1" Width="376" Height="280">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="Auto"  Name="textBlock4" Padding="0" Text="Generic ID" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="-20,0,20,0" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="Auto"  Name="textBlock5" Padding="0" Text="Generic Name" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="-10,20,10,-20" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="Auto"  Name="textBlock6" Padding="0" Text="Other Names" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="-15,43,15,-43" />
                <TextBox Height="25" Name="textBox8" Width="225" Margin="22,199,130,44" />
                <TextBox Height="25"  Name="textBox9" Width="225" Margin="20,147,131,95" />
                 <TextBox Height="25" Name="textBox11" Width="225" Margin="20,97,131,159" />
                <TextBox Height="25"  Name="textBox12" Margin="21,122,131,121" />
                <TextBox Height="25"  Name="textBox13" Width="225" Margin="20,159,131,52" />
                <TextBox Height="25"  Name="textBox14" Width="225" Margin="20,222,131,20" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

Just try whether this works out.I think the margin and height are resulting in the problem